# Replacing text according to list

Tags: python, text, replace

I have text in file, like this:

> One reason the Fed is likely to wait until early 2014 to begin easing
>   back on stimulus efforts is that policy makers there simply will not
>   know if the labor market is gaining or losing strength before then.
>   Not until December will the monthly jobs survey be free of the
>   shutdown static, and that report does not come out until early
>   January.
>
> The September jobs report was disappointing, with the economy adding
>   148,000 new jobs instead of the expected 185,000, but stocks rose on
>   anticipation that Fed stimulus efforts would continue well into 2014.

at another file i have list of replacement:

> January:Febryary
>   September:november
>   monthly:weekly

How can i do work to replace all words in text to replace according to replacement list?

```
Try this:
with open('t_.txt') as f3:
    with open ('egb.out') as w3:

        for line in f3:
            for line1 in w3:

                word,string = line1.split(':')
                print line.replace(word,string),
```

But work only for first line

Comment: I assume the horribly misspelled words are on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

After you have read the two files into strings, something along these lines should work

```
# text contains the first file
# replacements contains the list of replacement
for w in replacements.split(' '):
    if ':' in w:
        word,replacement = w.split(':')
        text = text.replace(word,replacement)
```

Comment: This will not take into account words ending/starting with a punctuation (like , and .).

Comment: word,replacement = w.split(':')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Can you show the replacement string that you used? There is likely extra whitespace. Try adding `replacement = replacement.strip()` before the loop.

Comment: And why is that the case, Michel? It's late so it's very possible I'm overlooking something.

Comment: `with open('t1.txt') as f3:
    with open ('t2.txt') as w3:

        for line in f3:
            for line1 in w3:

                word,string = line1.split(':')
                print line.replace(word,string),`  Try this, but do only first line

Comment: Yeah, but what is the contents of the file? And if you want to read one line at a time add `if ':' in line1`. This will make sure that there is a ':' in the line that you are searching for a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary, and something like this string (or read from a file, or whatever):

```
rep = {'January':'Febryary', 'September':'november', 'monthly':'weekly'}

s = """One reason the Fed is likely to wait until early 2014 to begin easing back on stimulus efforts is that policy makers there simply will not know if the labor market is gaining or losing strength before then. Not until December will the monthly jobs survey be free of the shutdown static, and that report does not come out until early January.

The September jobs report was disappointing, with the economy adding 148,000 new jobs instead of the expected 185,000, but stocks rose on anticipation that Fed stimulus efforts would continue well into 2014."""
```

You can then use this one-liner:

```
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(*y), rep.iteritems(), s)
```

Or use (in my opinion a more efficient) regular expression:

```
import re

rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems()) # makes sure things wont screw up
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys())) # create the pattern
result = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], s)
```

But really, if you are dealing with things like this, you should look at the [nltk (Natural Language Toolkit)](http://nltk.org/)